# New-NetIPAddress not working in WIndows Powershell: Invalid parameter InterfaceAliase Local Area Network

Tags: windows, powershell

My computer has a Windows 10 and I was following through Microsoft 98-366 Network Fundamentals book.
It had me to open Windows Powershell and type

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Local Area Network" -IPv4Address 192.168.1.101 -PrefixLength "24" -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1
```

Then I got the error that it can't find a parameter with the name IPv4Address. It'ns not a typo though, because above was directly copied from the book.

So when I looked up the documentations on New-NetIPAddress it seemed -IPv4Address is not an option and instead I have to use IPAddress. So I tried the below

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Local Area Network" -IPAddress 192.168.1.101 -PrefixLength "24" -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1
```

Then I got a new error saying

> New-NetIPAddress : Invalid parameter InterfaceAlias Local Area Network

but `InterfaceAlias` does exist in the documentations, so I'm not sure what causes it to be invalid.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Additionally, the documentation I looked up was this:
[Net-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netipaddress?view=win10-ps)

Comment: You need to wrap the IP addresses in quotes (`'192.168.1.101'`), since this parameter expects a string.

Comment: @Theo that is not needed. It will work without enclosing the IP addresses in double/single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the InterfaceAlias is not valid.

First look at all the network interfaces using the command `Get-NetIPInterface`. Here is the output in my PC:

```
InterfaceAlias
--------------
vEthernet (Wi-Fi)
vEthernet (VMware Network ) 2
vEthernet (VMware Network )
vEthernet (VirtualBox Host)
vEthernet (Ethernet)
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Local Area Connection* 10
Local Area Connection* 9
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
vEthernet (Wi-Fi)
vEthernet (VMware Network ) 2
vEthernet (VMware Network )
vEthernet (VirtualBox Host)
vEthernet (Ethernet)
VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Local Area Connection* 10
Local Area Connection* 9
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
```

Re-check by reading all properties with `Get-NetIPInterface | Format-List *` will help you identify which is the correct network interface you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I done what you told me and found out that the name "Local Area Network" was in my native language instead of English and this became the problem. I have an additional question though. When I had put in the right name and tried it again, I was denied access. Is it better to quit the tryout or is there a way to change the mode of the local area network? ( I'm on my os not that of VM)

Comment: Maybe run powershell as Administrator and then try? (If it has solved your problem, then you can click the large check mark)